# Input radio и input text

Tags: html, input, текст, background

Здравствуйте столкнулся с проблемой отключения флажка на input radio если вы вводите текст в input text
дело в том что я хочу сделать выбор картинки заднего фона и есть базовые 3 варианта а также вариант выбрать свой задний фон вставив туда url картинки, просто если вы выбрали 1 из 3 вариантов и ввели текст в input text то это может привести к ошибке что мне конечно же не нужно. Хочу узнать как можно решить такую проблему

Вот скрин заготовки

[image: скрин]

Answer (score 3):

```js
window.onload = function () { // Ожидаем загрузку документа
    let img = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); // Получаем все картинки по тегу
    let radio = document.getElementsByName('img'); // Получаем все радио кнопки по имени
    let input = document.getElementsByClassName('input')[0]; // Получаем поле ввода
    for(let i=0;i<img.length;i++){ // Для каждой картинки
        img[i].addEventListener('click', function () { // Прослушиваем нажатие, если нажали на картинку
            let src = img[i].src; // получаем ссылку из картинки
            radio[i].checked = true; // Делаем radio активным
            document.body.style.background = 'url('+src+')no-repeat'; // Загружаем background
            document.body.style.backgroundSize = '100%'; // Ставим размер
        })
        radio[i].addEventListener('click', function () { // Отслеживаем нажатие на сами поля radio
            let src = img[i].src; // получаем ссылку из картинки
            document.body.style.background = 'url('+src+')no-repeat'; // Загружаем background
            document.body.style.backgroundSize = '100%'; // Ставим размер
        })
    }
    input.oninput = function () { // При вводе текста в поле
        [...radio].forEach(function (c) { // Для каждой кнопки радио
            c.checked = false; // Убираем выбранный параметр
        })
    };
    input.onblur = function () { // При потери фокуса поля input
        let src1 = input.value; // Получаем введённые данные
        document.body.style.background = 'url('+src1+')no-repeat'; // СТавим эту ссылку на background
        document.body.style.backgroundSize = '100%'; // Растягиваем.
    }
}
```

```css
    img{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="img"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
<input type="radio" name="img"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
<input type="radio" name="img"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQEctYp5SaPSy0HTnt215V_W593S3iWVzgNvTIRSbdTtYtY1kge">
<br><input class="input">
```

Comment: спасибо большое))))))